# What's wrong with the following argument that every module is flat?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Okay, I know I'm doing something incredibly stupid here, but for whatever reason I can't figure out what.

As I understand it, an R-module M is flat iff $f : I \otimes_R M \to I M$ is an isomorphism for each $I < M$.

And since this map is surjective by definition, we just need to check that it's injective.

Consider an arbitrary element $s \in I \otimes_R M$.  We have

$$s = \sum_k j_k \otimes m_k =  \sum_k 1 \otimes j_k m_k = 1 \otimes \sum_k j_k m_k.$$

It follows that

$$f(s) = \sum_k j_k m_k$$

So $f(s)=0$ iff $s =0$, i.e. f is injective.

Comment: I think that the issue might be that $1$ is not in the ideal $I$ unless $I = R$, in which case everything else would hold (because $R$ is a flat $R$-module).

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$j_k \otimes m_k = 1 \otimes j_k m_k$ is not valid. Find out why!

Comment: For anyone having the same problem I was, note that (as msteve mentions in the comments) $1 \otimes j_k m_k$ is not a meaningful element of $I \otimes_R M$, since $1$ is not an element of $I$.